# Why did I get and unexpected error code H14 on Heroku?

Tags: python, git, heroku

I am getting many error code H14s on Heroku, and I am not quite sure how to resolve them. I am running a Windows computer.

I tried going on the Heroku website to resolve this issue. However, the problem that they suggested had me use the command "heroku ps:scale web=1". When I used this command, the console said that it "  Couldn't find that process type (web)." When I looked this up on Heroku, it said that my buildpacks were installed incorrectly. However, I only have one buildpack "heroku/python", so I cannot see how this could cause the error.

Here is the first error code that I am receiving, when I enter "heroku logs --tail"

```
2019-03-26T17:37:06.013914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=face-detector.herokuapp.com request_id=8c5dd093-2601-469e-8782-ec08b07919b2 fwd="143.229.241.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-26T17:37:06.989631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=face-detector.herokuapp.com request_id=091d4e7a-6883-4e4c-b528-2777fb6aa05c fwd="143.229.241.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-26T17:37:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-26T17:37:13.507225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=face-detector.herokuapp.com request_id=00aec941-e4c6-46b6-a641-0a2b5ecd6eac fwd="143.229.241.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-26T17:37:14.646479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=face-detector.herokuapp.com request_id=88c5bb9e-9468-4a8f-ad76-213c08af4273 fwd="143.229.241.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

When I try to amend the issue with "heroku ps:scale web=1", I get

```
Scaling dynos... !
!    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

Is it possible that there is something wrong with my Procfile? At the moment, my Procfile has

```
web: gunicorn app:FaceDetector
```

Comment: Heroku can be picky with the formatting of its own "infrastructure files" like `Procfile`, `runtime.txt`, etc. Try saving your `Procfile` with Unix-style line endings and make sure it doesn't contain any extraneous characters except a newline at the end. Also, it should be called exactly `Procfile`, with a capital `P` and no file extension.

Comment: @Chris Right now, my Procfile has only the characters provided in the post above, and has no file extension and has only the capital P.

Comment: What about the line endings?

Comment: @Chris Do I need line endings if the whole file is just one line? If so, what should the line ending be?

Comment: It's common for text files to always end with a newline. Your editor might even be doing that automatically. Try using Unix line endings.

Comment: Also, is your `Procfile` in the root project directory?

Comment: Does this help? https://help.heroku.com/W23OAFGK/why-am-i-seeing-couldn-t-find-that-process-type-when-trying-to-scale-dynos

Comment: @Chris This might be a stupid question, but is my root directory the app folder, or the folder that houses the app folder? As for the link, I had already tried it, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: The very top-level folder of your Git repository.

Comment: @Chris Thank you. As it turns out, adding the newline character seemed to fix the problem. Now I have a new error to fix, but that's another problem for potentially another thread if I cannot figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I tried the solution "saving your Procfile with Unix-style line endings and make sure it doesn't contain any extraneous characters except a newline at the end" and it didn't work.

My solution approaches:

1. Make sure your Procfile is correct

   - Procfile is Procfile, not ProcFile, profile, procfile...
   - Procfile.txt (or any filetype) is INCORRECT. Just Procfile.
   - Procfile should be in the root directory aka "very top-level folder of your Git repository"
   - Content in Procfile must be accurate. No redundant or strange characters, space, new lines, comments

     - My app is a `web` (Python with Flask) then the content should be `web: gunicorn <filename>:<variable_name>`. Example: `web gunicorn application:app`. Gunicorn = a production-quality web server. (Flask’s built-in web server is “good enough for testing but probably not what you want to use in production.”). `application` = `application.py` in **root dir**. `app` = `Flask(__name__)`
     - Heroku has different process types apart from `web` so you should check their Docs.
2. If Procfile is WRONG and you fixed, and things didn't change.

   - Must remove Procfile (`git rm`) from git, create a new correct Procfile, then commit and push again.
3. Still not working after #1 and #2

   - Go to the `Overview` tab in your Heroku project, check `Dyno formation`. If you see a message saying there is no process type recorded. A simple scenario is that you might forget to log in your Heroku account.

     - Check by typing in your terminal `heroku ps:scale web=1 --app <app-name-registered-in-Heroku>`. If you see `Invalid credentials provided. heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: Command failed: heroku login`

My personal conclusion was that the **'forget to log in and run `git push heroku master`'** was the root cause of H14 Error. There are of courses other issues that indirectly cause this error but I hope my answer narrow down your search for answers.